# Cmake clang building with -fsanitize=address

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I'm trying to build my executable with the -fsanitize=address flag. The flags set are -

```
CXX FLAGS: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc  -fsanitize=address
```

but I get a warning and error thrown -

```
[build] clang-cl : error : invalid argument '/MDd' not allowed with '-fsanitize=address' [C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\Desktop\Repos\horizon\out\build\Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release\src\Tests\LockedLookupTableTest.vcxproj]
[build] clang-cl : message : AddressSanitizer doesn't support linking with debug runtime libraries yet
```

I can't see `/MDd` flag used anywhere what could this be linked to?